# How do I run "git rebase -i --root" in JGit?

Tags: java, git, github, rebase, jgit

Does anyone know how I run the following Git command in JGit?

```
git rebase -i --root
```

I can use this command fine using git on the command line, but can't find how to do this in JGit...

Answer (score 1):

The [JGit cookbook for rebase](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/2c8b366bdc5f40bcf3b100cc31de8430571e4149/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/RebaseToOriginMaster.java) references the [`RebaseCommand` class](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/f5fa1eaf399275e9cc4a6418ecadfa04c10060b6/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/RebaseCommand.java) and [its tests](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/f5fa1eaf399275e9cc4a6418ecadfa04c10060b6/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/RebaseCommandTest.java).

None of them mention "`--root`", which does not seem supported.

Comment: that is a shame. I will add it as a feature request, thanks.

Comment: @user1974753 OK, let me know (in the comments) of the URL of your feature request: I will vote for it ;)

Comment: The feature request is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=443412. Unfortunately it's gotten no response so far in three years.

Comment: @gbear605 Darn it! I just have voted on the issue page. That will show them ;)